# Имя позиции ListView в TextView

Tags: android, listview, textview

Я хочу чтобы `TextView` показал имя выбранной позиции `ListView`.
Это аудио книга и мне нужно чтоб пользователь знал какой трек играет.

```
private final Handler handler = new Handler();
    private final String[] listContent = { "0000", "0001",  };
    private final int[] resID = { R.raw.a0001, R.raw.a0000,  };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initViews();
        // Initializing variables
    }

    private void initViews() {


        tb_title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tb_title);
        mp = new MediaPlayer();




        mainList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listContent);
        mainList.setAdapter(adapter);


        mainList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
                                    int position, long id)   {
                playSong(position);


                            }

        });



    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну так просто сделайте это...

```
mainList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id)   {
        playSong(position);
        tb_title.setText(listContent[position]);
             }
});
```

Comment: Все работает! Спасибо большое.) Я не знаю как вас поблагодарить, я навичек и мне это очень сложно все...

Comment: @МухаммаднакшубандиОмаров, пожалуйста) Голос за и отмечание пряным ответа меня более чем устраивает в качестве благодарности)